# How can I make a conditional join with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int AId;
    public int A1;
    public int A2;
    public int A3;
    public int BId;
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int BId;
    public int B1;
    public int B2;
}
```

I have this view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int AId;
    public int A1;
    public int A2;
    public int A3;
    public int? B1;
    public int? B2;
}
```

I want to run this Entity Framework query:

```
  from a in mydbcontext.EntityA
  where <conditions>
  select new MyViewModel
  {
       AId = a.AId,
       A1 = a.A1,
       A2 = a.A2,
       A3 = a.A3,
       B1 = null,
       B2 = null
  };
```

And sometimes I need to run this query:

```
  from a in mydbcontext.EntityA
  join b in mydbcontext.EntityB on a.BId equals b.BId
  where <conditions>
  select new MyViewModel
  {
      AId = a.AId,
      A1 = a.A1,
      A2 = a.A2,
      A3 = a.A3,
      B1 = b.B1,
      B2 = b.B2
  };
```

I want to write this 2 queries in one query with a condition.

I have tried to do this:

```
  var query = from a in mydbcontext.EntityA
  where <conditions>
  select new MyViewModel
  {
     AId = a.AId,
     A1 = a.A1,
     A2 = a.A2,
     A3 = a.A3,
     B1 = null,
     B2 = null
  };

  if (myconditionforjoin)
  {
     query = from q in query
     join b in mydbcontext.EntityB on q.BId equals b.BId
     select new MyViewModel
     {
         // Is there a way to put a wildcard there for including all q fields ?
         B1 = b.B1,
         B2 = b.B2     
     }
  }
```

But this syntax is not good for me because in fact I have a lot of calculated fields in first query and i don't want to put twice the same code

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes i have no problem for using lambda syntax

Comment: **NB:** Entity Framework and Entity Framework Core are complete different beasts. You should tag your question with the one you're using, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sharing calculations for `EntityA` fields, just save all calculations until the end:

```
bool shouldJoin = true;

var query = 
    from a in mydbcontext.EntityA
    where <conditions>
    // `B = (EntityB)null` will also work in this example
    select new { A = a, B = new EntityB() };

if (myconditionforjoin)
{
     query = 
        from q in query
        join b in mydbcontext.EntityB on q.A.BId equals b.BId
        // Retain A values
        select new { A = a.A, B = b };
}

var final = 
    from q in query
    let A = q.A
    let B = q.B
    select new MyViewModel
    {
        AId = A.AId,
        A1 = A.A1,
        A2 = A.A2,
        A3 = A.A3,

        B1 = B.B1,
        B2 = B.B2
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i need a solution without sub objects in my viewmodel

Comment: Ok, I think I just came up with something much easier.